# Powershell list with IPAddress, Prefixlength and Computernames

Tags: powershell, hostname

I've write a PS Script, that gives me all IP Addresses and Prefixlength of Servers from a text file. See code:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\XX_YY\Desktop\test_hostname_file.txt
invoke-command -computername $computers -Credential $cred -scriptblock {get-netipaddress -AddressFamily IPv4 } | where {$_.ipaddress -like "10.*"} | ft -AutoSize IPaddress, prefixlength
```

This Script gives me the result as a table. But I need the Computernames as well in the table.

have you an idea how I can handle this?

Cheers Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would do it in another way, but to stick to your question:

You can use the Automatic variable `$ENV:ComputerName` to get the computer name and add it to the output using a PS Object

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\XX_YY\Desktop\test_hostname_file.txt

invoke-command -computername $computers -Credential $cred -scriptblock {
$IP = get-netipaddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | where {$_.ipaddress -like "10.*"} 
$Row = "" | Select Computer,IPaddress,prefixlength
$Row.Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Row.IPaddress = $IP.IPaddress
$Row.prefixlength = $IP.prefixlength
return $row
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! exactly